# Python bus error problem when writing to database

Tags: python, mysql, macos, zlib, bus-error

Whenever I try to write/update/delete from MySQL I've been experiencing a bus error problem since I've installed [zlib](http://zlib.net/) on my machine. Has anyone else experienced this problem? There's no error message or anything. Python just prints Bus error to console and quits. I can read from database without any problems though.

Could anyone give some hints or directions what I should do?

Comment: Maybe your request got on the wrong bus...

Comment: What version of Python are you using?  Show the output of `which python` and `python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)'` and `python -c 'import zlib; print(zlib.__file__)'`

Comment: I'm using Python 2.6.1. This is what I get;

which python =>
/usr/bin/python

python -c 'import sys; print(sys.version)' =>
2.6.1 (r261:67515, Dec 17 2009, 00:59:15) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5646)]

python -c 'import zlib; print(zlib.__file__)' =>
/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6/lib/python2.6/lib-dynload/zlib.so

Answer (score 2):

It is really hard recommending something useful without (much) more informations. But try:

```
sudo dtruss python your_python_program
```

you will get a long syscall trace, what can be the 1st step to figure out what is wrong.